# How to make derivative as a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
  g[z_] := z^2
  l[z_] := D[g[z], z]
```

How to make the derivative of a function as a new function. Here I am showing the simple case.

Comment: Try `l[z_] := g'[z]`

Comment: `l = Derivative[1][g]`

Comment: I want to further use the l, as a function of x. such that for the above case l[3] should give me 6 answer.

Comment: You should learn about [immediate and delayed assignments](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html). In your case, by using an immediate assignment there is no problem: `l[z_] = D[g[z], z]`

Comment: yes, it will not be a problem. but I wanted to understand why here defining a function I don't need semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `Derivative` and pure function to do this.

```
l = Derivative[1][#^2 &]; (* l = Derivative[1][x |-> x^2] *)
l[x] 
l[z]
l[2]
l[3]
```

> 2x,2z,4,6

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, an [immediate assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) fixes the problem:

```
g[z_] := z^2
l[z_] = D[g[z], z]
(*    2 z    *)

l[3]
(*    6    *)
```